# jQuery passing variable values into child functions

Tags: jquery, function, variables, each

It returns undefined for var "el" the way I have this code

```
$('.element').each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(el) {
        el.css({ marginTop: -100 });
    }, 550);
    $(window).resize(function(el) {
        setTimeout(function(el) {
            el.css({ marginTop: -100 }); //this is where el is undefined
        }, 550);            
    })
});
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because of `el` as function arguments. Try to remove them.

```
$('.element').each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        el.css({ marginTop: -100 });
    }, 550);
    $(window).resize(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            el.css({ marginTop: -100 }); //this is where el is undefined
        }, 550);            
    })
});
```

And don't forget to crucify me if I'm wrong :P

EDIT:
Just to explain what's going on, the `function` in `resize` is passed an `event` object, so it overwrites the `el` variable you have set. `Event` isn't a `jQuery` object, so you cant call `css` function on it.

Comment: Thanks man, issue solved, now I got the point, but the function is not doing what I need, have to dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

The `el` parameters that you're passing into the `setTimeout` and the `resize` event are unnecessary,

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/atg7F/

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the `el`. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Um7Tp/1/

```
$('.element').each(function(){
    var el = $(this); // this var was overwritten...
    setTimeout(function() { // here
        console.log(el);
        el.css({ marginTop: -100 });
    }, 550);

    $(window).resize(function() { // here
        setTimeout(function() { // and here
            el.css({ marginTop: -100 }); 
            console.log(el);
        }, 550);            
    })
});
```